# ten out of ten horseshoes -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

> "Mastering Regular Expressions is the definitive guide to the subject, and an outstanding
>   resource that belongs on every programmer's bookshelf. **Ten out of Ten Horseshoes**."
> —Jason Menard, Java Ranch

What does that mean?

Comment: It is a (humorous) rating, like "5 out of 5 stars". Note the name of the organization, Java *Ranch*.

Comment: As TRomano says; if you check out the reviews at [http://www.javaranch.com/bunkhouse/books.jsp] you will see that books are rated with 1-10 horseshoes.

Comment: Fiddling with the site for a while, I found the search page on the site StoneyB had mentioned, e.g. http://www.javaranch.com/bunkhouse/bookSearch.jsp?title=java&author=&publisher=&isbn=&review-author=&content=&category=ANY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the web site's rating system.

It's common, in America anyway, to rate the quality of something on a scale, usually from 1 to 10, sometimes from 1 to 5. So if you say, "I give this one a 5 on a scale of 1 to 10", you're saying it's in the middle. Of course you could use any number for the highest rating but it's common to use either 5 or 10.

This is often described as a number of "stars". Like, "I give this movie 4 stars". See Amazon.com, for example, where they routinely rate products with 1 to 5 stars.

Sometimes people use something other than stars to be consistent with the theme of their book or website or wherever they are giving these ratings. In this case, the site is called "Java Ranch", so the writer is apparently trying to have a ranch theme, and so he uses horseshoes instead of stars.